# Insert several numbers from array in to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
var prices = [9.15, 10.10, 13.15, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
var premiumPrice = [9.15, 10.10, 13.15, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
```

When the html document is loading I need to insert number from array called "prices" to `<div>` with id corresponding to index of array and "premiumPrice" to another `<div>`. I figured that html document might look something like this (note where is id):

```
<div class="header" id="1">
    <h2>BTC <span>1,00</span><em>  /Month</em></h2>

    <div class="price blue">SMALL</div>
</div><!--/ header -->


<div class="details">
    <ul>
        <li><b>1 000</b> sites</li>
    </ul>

<div class="specialPromo">
    <input type="checkbox"><label>Add <b>PREMIUM</b><br><em>(+<span id="1">0,15</span> usd/month)</em></label>

</div><!--/ specialPromo -->
</div><!--/ details -->
    <a href="/cos/cos/ID" class="btn ">SELECT</a>
</div><!--/ item -->
```

After pressing the checkbox to div header must be returned premiumPrice+price (from the array).

I don't know how to do this job.

Comment: Please copy your *actual* HTML in to the question, not a screenshot of it, along with the JS code you've written yourself in an attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: @Roy For this moment the problem I'm solved by using regular expressions which take number from html file (in the code which is pasted a 5 line from the bottom (input) and 2 from the top). After clicking on the button (class btn) numbers are taken from html, they are added and thrown to the line 2 (in the above example)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you get an element and set its inner value.  There are other ways but im not exactly sure what it is your trying to do so this is the most generic way i could think of.  this is a good starting point.

```
element = document.getElementById('1');

element.innerHTML = 'someValue'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
var prices = [9.15, 10.10, 13.15, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
//loop through prices
for (var i=0;i<prices.length;i++){
    var idString = i.toString();
    //get the element and 
    document.getElementById(idString).innerHTML = prices[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>

    <script>
        var prices = [9.15, 10.10, 13.15, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
        var premiumPrice = [9.15, 10.10, 13.15, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];


        window.addEventListener( 'load', function(){
            var id = document.getElementsByClassName( 'header' )[ 0 ];
            var price = id.querySelector( 'span' );

            price.textContent = prices[ id.getAttribute( 'id' ) ];

            document.getElementsByTagName( 'input' )[ 0 ]
                .addEventListener( 'click', function(){
                    var price_specialPromo = document.getElementsByClassName( 'specialPromo' )[ 0 ]
                        .querySelector( 'span' );

                    price_specialPromo.textContent = prices[ id.getAttribute( 'id' ) ] + premiumPrice[ id.getAttribute( 'id' ) ];
                });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header" id="1">
        <h2>BTC <span>1,00</span><em>  /Month</em></h2>

        <div class="price blue">SMALL</div>
    </div><!--/ header -->


    <div class="details">
        <ul>
            <li><b>1 000</b> sites</li>
        </ul>

        <div class="specialPromo">
            <input type="checkbox"><label>Add <b>PREMIUM</b><br><em>(+<span id="1">0,15</span> usd/month)</em></label>
        </div><!--/ specialPromo -->
    </div><!--/ details -->

    <a href="/cos/cos/ID" class="btn ">SELECT</a>
</body>
</html>
```